# How can I display a large number of websocket messages in a browser?

Tags: javascript, python, html, websocket

I work on a project where I am building a web application that reads tasks from a log file and sends data as a websocket message to the browser. I am usnig Django as a server. I have a problem when I want to display all the messages in browser. Due to the large number of messages the browser becaome unresponsive. To display messgegs in browser I am usning `.innerhtml`.

Here is my code:

Function that accepts a message:

```
    socket.onmessage = (e) => {
        let consoleOutput = document.getElementById("console-output");
        consoleOutput.innerHTML += e.data + "<br>";
        console.log("message", e);
    };
```

Function which sends message:

```
    def websocket_receive(self, event):
        response = json.loads(event["text"])
        app_name = response.get("app_name")
        path_to_logs_file = f"{pathlib.Path.home()}/logs/{app_name}/file.log"
        process = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-f", path_to_logs_file],
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   )
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        while True:
            decoded_line = process.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8")
            if decoded_line == '' and process.poll() is not None:
                self.send({
                    "type": "websocket.close"
                })
                break
            else:
                self.send({
                    "type": "websocket.send",
                    "text": str(decoded_line).strip()
                })
```

How can I speed up appending data to the element? I will appreciate any usefull advice.

Comment: `consoleOutput.innerHTML +=`  This is constantly concatenating a string, and then causing the DOM to re-render,.. You will find it much better using `document.createElement("div")` and then use `appendChild`.  Or if you just want text without a `div`, use `createTextNode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your question it appears your wanting to use websockets to show a log.

Appending to innerHTML constantly becomes very inefficient after a while.

So what you might want to do is accessing the DOM directly..

Below is an example, it simply shows the current time ins `ms`, and also prunes old entries after a while to prevent memory growing.

```js
const cd = document.querySelector("code");

setInterval(() => {
  const txt = document.createTextNode(
    `Current Time in ms: ${Date.now()}\n`);
  cd.appendChild(txt);
  if (cd.childNodes.length > 500) cd.childNodes[0].remove();
}, 10);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
code {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<code></code>
```

Comment: It works faster, but now I have a problem, when websocket do not send message it does not stop displaying the data but start displaing old messages very fast.

Comment: @MihaelWaschl  Are you still using `setInterval` as that was just there for testing purposes only, you just need to put the `appendChild` etc into your `onmessage`..

Comment: Yes I forgot to remove it. Thank you it solve my problem.